# Gradle cannot start Java

Tags: java, gradle

Following the [libgdx tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle), I created a Gradle project which runs fine on my desk pc but cannot start Java on my laptop.

Both my machines use Gradle 2.10 on Arch Linux 4.3.3-2 with GNOME Shell 3.18.3 and Java 1.8.0_66 OpenJDK.

This is the error I get on my laptop:

```
$ gradle desktop:run 
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:classes UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':desktop:run'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java''
```

The file `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java` exists, has all the necessary permissions for all users and can be executed manually without problems.

Comment: @piotrek1543 I think you are using some IDE. I am using the command line.

Comment: run using `--stacktrace` and `--info` to get more info on what happens

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @sasha199568 This was a while ago but I don't remember having solved that.

Comment: I got a similar error because of using the wrong version of Java and not setting up the correct environment variables for Java.

Comment: @akki: Thanks for the reply! Unforunately this was a long time ago and I don't use Gradle anymore so I can't check but it seems I can't close my question with that reason.

Comment: @KonradHöffner I totally agree that my comment is not enough reason to close the comment, neither was that my intention  

Just wrote that comment for anyone who might land up on this page and try out that trick :)
Thanks.

Comment: I had a problem with similar symptoms to this that ended up being due to the `workingDir` parameter of the `JavaExec` gradle task type. Apparently setting the `workingDir` makes gradle unable to resolve the `java` executable's absolute path for some reason.